# Firefox zoom affected by windows display settings

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, zooming

So apparently, in one of the last update, Firefox decided to take into account the display settings of windows. (see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962990?page=1 ) As a result, if the display settings of windows is set to Medium (125%), firefox will zoom in while the other browser display the website normally.

But what i wan't to know is if there is any option for a developer to prevent this zoom in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

With firefox, you can use media queries to detect zoom levels / resolutions

Check out this example (only works in FF)
http://dev.jeffersonscher.com/nozoom.html

```
@media (max-resolution: 91.95dpi) {
  body {font-size:17.8px;}
}

@media (min-resolution: 100.05dpi) and (max-resolution: 115dpi) {
  body {font-size:14.5px;}
}

@media (min-resolution: 115.05dpi) and (max-resolution: 124dpi) {
  body {font-size:13.2px;}
}

@media (min-resolution: 124.05dpi) and (max-resolution: 138dpi) {
  body {font-size:12px;}
}

@media (min-resolution: 138.05dpi) and (max-resolution: 149dpi) {
  body {font-size:10.6px;}
}

@media (min-resolution: 149.05dpi) {
  body {font-size:9.2px;}
}
```